# Programaticly add UI asset to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, arrays, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am new to iOS dev and there are questions I have that aren't covered in tutorial basics.
With that said, is it common to iterate over an array and programaticly add UI assets to a view?

Example:

```
NSString *myPlistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:PeopleStubPlist ofType:@"plist"];
peopleStub = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPlistFile];

for (int i = 0; i < peopleStub.count; i++) {
    // add UI asset (UIImage) here...
}
```

The goal is to create a Tiled list of "user avatars"... Since it is a tiled list, the UITableView is not an option.

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: Far more common than you would probably expect. Since iOS doesn't have anything like layout controllers (per se), you generally end up defining everything's `frame` such that they lay out as you want them to. Some controls, like `UITableView`, do this in such a way as to make you think that it is a layout controller (and by some definitions, I suppose it is), but it is still technically laying everything out manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - I found a solution that worked here in this blog post.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker

I'm still learning iOS and finding myself angry and confused most of the day...

Comment: Yes, this was also the solution I found. Thanks.